# Get dependant probabilities in multiclassification

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, prediction, probability, metric

After training my CatBoostClassifier model I call get_proba function which returns me list of probabilities. The problem starts from an another point... I transfer that data into dataframe then to Excel after what I sum all float numbers in my list and get numbers approximately equal to 2.

(Example: `0,980831511  0,99695788  2,99173E-13 1,63919E-15 7,35072E-14 4,82846E-16` . Their sum is equal to `1,977789391` )

Parameters which were used:

```
'loss_function': 'MultiClassOneVsAll', 
 'eval_metric': 'ZeroOneLoss',
```

The problem is that I need to get dependant type of probabilities, so I get something more like: `0.2 0.5 0.1 0.2` where their sum will be equal to `1` and the highest probability (which might be obvious) is in the second category (which equals to `0.5`)

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Why do use `MultiClassOneVsAll`? Normally this means that you're doing [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), not [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification). As a result, the classes are predicted independently from each other. If you want to obtain dependent posterior probabilities and a single class predicted for each instance, you should used the standard multiclass setting (one vs rest).

Comment: @Erwan thanks a lot. Will try it now and say how it went :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've completed several tests and here is what I got...
First of all, I've used different objectives aka loss functions and metrics, so if you need to get "dependant" probability you may use everything (If I am not right, correct me in comment section or wherever else :) ), but `loss_function` *multiclassova* (in other words OneVsAll). Anyway, I've used *multiclassova* as eval metric and everything seemed right... (In case something goes wrong, I will edit or add comment to this answer)
In case you use OneVsAll (if someone doesn't know) you get this result
[image: Using multiclassova]

In other case, as you see, sum of all events equals to 1, while in last case it could vary from 0.5 to 2.0
[image: Using other loss_function]

Again thanks for clarifying @Erwan, because I didn't notice such a silly mistake :)